# Re: a sign on your residence: The Smiths vs. The Smiths’

Tags: grammatical-number

I know the former is the generally accepted usage, as that’s all I’ve ever seen over the years; meaning, by extension, "The Smiths ..live here" – presumably; whilst the second example implies, "The Smiths’ Home", which seems to me an obviously superior proposition for a sign on a residence.

My bias makes me suspect the former is just a pragmatic simplification that has become standard practice (but then, so is the latter an incomplete shortcut.)

What might a pedantic English instructor think if driving by such a sign, *The Smiths’*, and why?

Answer (score 3):

The sign over the store says *Tiffany & Co.*, not *Tiffany & Co.'s* even though it is identifying *Tiffany & Co.'s **store***.  I think your first thought, *here are the Smiths*, is the better reading of the sign.

Comment: This reminds me of the Strunk & White serial comma.  It is my supposition that firm signs over the decades are the cause of people preferring to drop the serial comma as a matter of standard form, vs. using it as a powerful indicator of relation (e.g. “John, Fritz and Beth.” - implying Fritz and Beth are together – a serial comma would not.)  I’m wary of corporate usage as definitive proper usage.  But I really don’t know squat.  This I do know.

Comment: In the movie, Lucy Gallant (1955), she has her neon store sign read, “Gallant’s Inc.”

Answer (score 3):

The fewer apostrophes in life, the better. If you really have to display your name in this way, some alternatives are *Mr and Mrs Smith, Mary and John Smith* and *The Smith Family*.

Comment: That's just because if you put up a sign per the OP's example, people might think you were advertising a divided nation.