# "Welcome to the Jones__": Plural or Plural Possessive?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

When making a welcome sign, what form of the name Jones would you use?  ("Welcome to the Jones__")

Comment: Essentially answered at [Party at the Johnsons's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119530/party-at-the-johnsonss).

Comment: Are you welcoming the Jones clan or are they throwing a party?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct possessive for nouns ending in "‑s"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)

Answer (score 2):

To me, a possessive seems fitting in this context. But I would think you would want a plural: just as "the house of the Smith family" can be called "the Smiths' (house)", it seems to me that "the house of the Jones family" should be expressed as "the Joneses' (house)".

So my recommendation for a sign is:

> Welcome to the Joneses'

based on the fact that for a family with the name "Smith", I would use

> Welcome to the Smiths'

(The following question is very similar, but closed for some unclear reason: [Re: a sign on your residence: The Smiths vs. The Smiths’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77565/re-a-sign-on-your-residence-the-smiths-vs-the-smiths). I disagree with the answers there.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with "Joneses":

> The plural of Jones is Joneses, ‐es being added as an indicator of the plurality of a word of which the singular form ends in s, as in dresses or messes. The apposition of the much misused apostrophe to the word Jones does not pluralize it. 
> <sub>Source: [Keeping up with the Jones’ or Joneses?](https://academic.oup.com/bja/article/90/5/708/270106/Keeping-up-with-the-Jones-or-Joneses)</sub>

Comment: Why shouldn't the possessive form (Jones's) be used here? It usually is for establishments / residences.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My reading of the question was that the Joneses were being welcomed, not that that one was being welcomed to the Jones's.  *(I interpreted the possessive tag as a question on whether the apostrophe would indicate a plurality :)*

Comment: But note that this is by no means a given. Look at the other answers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth agreed.  *(this was just a quickie attempt)*

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are referring to the house of the Jones family or in any other way that makes it possessive 'Joneses' would be correct otherwise Jones' or Jones's are both correct but "Jones's" is preferred because it more closely represents the spoken English.

Answer (score 0):

It somewhat depends on if you want to intend possession of something. You likely do because the implication is "Welcome to the Jones' [house]".

For that reason I would go with Jones'. If you are just pluralizing Jones, then, yes, it's Joneses. As in, "We are the Joneses.". In your case you are wanting a sign that indicates it's the home of the Jones family, the home you possess or own. So, Jones', whether you explicitly use the word house/home or not, seems to be the right word.

[Link to answer on pluralizing names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/what-is-the-correct-possessive-for-nouns-ending-in-s)